# Gitlab CI tag-based release pipeline only on master

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am looking for a way to ensure that some jobs (release) in Gitlab CI only run if the branch is master and the used tag matches a specific pattern. To do that I have used the following statements, but for some reason, Gitlab does not recognize branch and tag at the same time and it appears that this statement is never true.

```
building:
   stage: build
   only:
      refs:
         - master
      variables:
         - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~  /^v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?/
   script:
      - echo "Start building"
```

I have tried the same script with `CI_COMMIT_TAG` as well, but it didn't work.

I cannot use `-tags` for the `only` section as it will be triggered by any tags, no matter what the tag format is.

P.S: I am using the following commands to add a release tag to `master`.

```
git tag -a v2.1.3 -m "Releasing version v2.1.3"
git push --tags
```